# TabContainer in modal popup

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to use a ajaxToolkit:TabContainer in an AJAX modal popup. The problem is that I get a javascript error in Internet Explorer 8. It does work in Internet Explorer 9 and in Firefox!

```
htmlfile: Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus.
```

I don't get the error if I display the modal popup by default, or if I delete all ajaxToolkit:TabPanel elements in the ajaxToolkit:TabContainer.

Is there an option on the TabContainer to somehow not set a focus?

Here is an example that can be used to reproduce the problem with test.aspx

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSystem" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <h2>Test</h2>

        <asp:Button ID="cmdPopup" runat="server" CssClass="button btn" Text="Neuen Eintrag erfassen" OnClick="CmdPopupOpen" />

            <asp:Panel ID="panList" runat="server"  CssClass="modalPopup" Width="500px">

                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upDetail" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>

                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upData" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                        <br />
                                        <div class="modal">
                                        <div id="divHeader" runat="server" class="modal-header"><h2 class="messageboxh2">Task Messages</h2></div>



                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Task Typ: " />
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTaskType" runat="server">

                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                        <br /><br />
                                       <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="tConNew" runat="server" Height="150px" 
                                              >
                                            <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" ID="tPanInstant" HeaderText="Sofort" >
                                                <ContentTemplate>
                                                </ContentTemplate>

                                            </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>

                                        </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>     
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                <br/>
                                <asp:Button ID="cmdClose" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="Abbrechen" />
                                <asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="Speichern" onclick="MpeSave" />
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </asp:Panel>


            <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlPopup" runat="server" 
                    TargetControlID="lblDummyUpload"
                    PopupControlId="panList" 
                    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" 
                    PopupDragHandleControlID="divHeader" 
                    RepositionMode="None" 
                    CancelControlID="cmdClose"
                     />

            <asp:Button id="lblDummyUpload" runat="server" style="display:none" />  


    </ContentTemplate>        
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and the test.aspx.cs

```
 public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void MpeSave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mdlPopup.Hide();
    }

    protected void CmdPopupOpen(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mdlPopup.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show a reduced sample where this issue can be reproduced? Which version of the toolkit are you using? Does it work when you open the popup from codebehind? `ModalPopupExtender1.Show();`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I added a an example that raises the error.

Comment: I'm afraid i cannot reproduce it with IE9 in IE8 mode. Unfortunately i have no IE8 here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10805993/360171

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could "fix" the bug by using an older version of the AJAX Control Toolkit as suggested here: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27051

Comment: You can download the version from July 2011. However, Yuriy's solution in the comments above also works without needing to revert versions.

Answer (score 0):

As wrote before, it is bug inside AjaxToolkit it self.
The latest release of AjaxToolkit (September 2012) does not fixing this bug, so wait for updates.

Stable AjaxToolkit release without this bug is July 2011.